# Issues on migrating from Microsoft ODBC Driver to Oracle ODBC Driver

Tags: oracle, odbc, resultset

When i was using Microsft ODBC Driver, i was able to execute Oracle Stored Procedures by assigning the below String to ODBC Command :-

```
{call package1.procedure1({resultset 10,p_output_param1,p_output_param2,p_output_param3})}
```

Now after changing to Oracle ODBC Driver in 64 bit machine, its throwing an error that "identifier "p_output_param1" must be declared". I am not sure as to what is that i am missing. Can anyone please clarify whether there needs to be a syntax change?

Comment: I think you need to replace the named parameters with "?" placeholders.

Comment: I changed to the below call :- 

`{call package1.procedure1({resultset 10,?,?,?})}`

But again this resulted in the exception "**A first chance exception of System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException occurred in System.Data.dll**".

Comment: Also, those 3 parameters(p_output_param1,p_output_param2,p_output_param3) are output parameters within my stored procedures.

Comment: @OldProgrammer : I changed to the call :- {call package1.procedure1({resultset 10,?,?,?})} But again this resulted in the exception **"A first chance exception of System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException occurred in System.Data.dll"**. 


Can you share as to how to use the resultset which we were using as per the way stated in the below link :- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/174679

Answer (score 0):

I believe the proper ODBC syntax is:

{call package.procedure(10,?,?,?)}

assuming 10 is what you want to pass to the first procedure parameter and the procedure has 3 other parameters.

Comment: The first parameter that you see in that call is not input parameter. Its the resultset as specified in the below link :-
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/174679